# Are we allowed to speak in native language in GIS.SE chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat, internationalization

Especially on technical issues, it is hard to use/find the right word or sentence in a foreign language (in English for many people here). I occasionally don't post an answer to a question which I know its solution because I have difficulties explaining the solution in English. Therefore, I usually answer code-related questions because no need to write long and sophisticated sentences.

Sometimes, I realize, from his/her name or location, that the questioner speaks in my native language. And it takes a long time to ask him/her some details in English. Therefore I would like him/her to join a new chat room to discuss the question or answer etc. in my native tongue.

Are we allowed to speak in native language in a new chat room? What is the policy in GIS.SE?

Comment: Here are related questions on meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136259/641151 And here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/641151

Comment: @Aaron I read that post. But I couldn't understand the answer. Because "*The short answer is: whatever language the other folks present in the room are comfortable speaking*" means it is allowed to speak in another language. But "**Long answer: chat is not a venue for private discussion, and most of these sites are dedicated to English-speaking content**"" means "it is not allowed" or "we shouldn't". Am I wrong?

Comment: On another answer, it is said "*There isn't any such restriction, but each community can have their own policies.*". So what is the policy in GIS.SE?

Comment: Not exactely an answer, but maybe still relevant for your purpose: there were already questions/answers here on GIS SE translated to english with https://www.deepl.com - an example here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382116/88814 (see at the very end)

Comment: @babel When it comes to technical issue, translators usually fail. I know because I frequently use them to get insight.

Comment: Of course, just as a auxiliary tool for longer text to get a basic translation as a starting point that should be improved by a human (maybe easier than writing the text from scratch). For QGIS specific terms, I personally often use this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367037/88814

Comment: Don't forget that our community is also willing to help improve grammar, spelling, technical terms and other possible language barriers. Thats why we have the ability to edit posts of others (or make suggestions if you have low rep). To give my two cents on the original question: personally I wouldnt mind if you chat in your mothers tongue, but no idea about SE/SO's policies about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not consider this to be a formal GIS SE policy because the site operates mostly on guidelines.  However, the only [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93002/215590) to [Policy: Is it OK to have dedicated foreign-language chat rooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92996/policy-is-it-ok-to-have-dedicated-foreign-language-chat-rooms) suggests that it is fine to set up a chat room that is dedicated to a language other than English.

I think you should feel free to try doing what you suggest and the worst thing that can happen is that someone finds a Meta Q&A saying the opposite to the one that I found, and then we can seek formal clarification as to whether it is OK or not.